# Creating a calculated property in Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have a core data model that's hooked up to a Storyboard GUI.(Xcode 9 and SWIFT 4) I now want to add a property which is derived from two others. I have an Entity called Workout and two of it's properties "rpe" and "seconds" are combined to create a new property "rpeTSS". I have declared "repTSS" as an attribute in my core data model. I've set it to transient.

I have tried using the "make NSManagedObject subclass..." option under the Editor menu but this seemed to produce files with errors. I tried subclassing the generated Workout class but couldn't figure out how to bind that in to the GUI.

I then made an extension to Workout:

```
extension Workout{

    public override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        if key == "rpeTSS"{
            return (100/49)*rpe*rpe*Double(seconds)/3600
        }else{return super.value(forKey: key)}
    }
}
```

I'll be honest this doesn't 'feel' right. Anyway it (kind of) works. I do now get the correct value for rpeTSS and it shows up in my gui. However if I make changes to rpe and/or seconds the GUI doesn't update.

I'm guessing the method above is a bit of a hack and thus circumvents various messaging that gets the GUI to update.

What is the correct way to add derived properties within core data? I'm trying to achieve this in a way that means if I add anything to my data model I don't have to go re-writing of the code for the derived properties.

Comment: Could you make an object of your Entity class and set the properties there? And then whenever you change rpe or seconds update the rpeTSS property as well.

Comment: not sure what you mean. The Entity class is auto generated in XCode.  I tried subclassing it but hit two problems - 1. how to make the ManagedObject an instance of my subclass and bind to the subclass in the GUI; and 2. I kept getting errors that my calculated properties weren't key value compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution I came up with looks and feels correct. It requires overriding keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey:) as follows:

```
extension Workout{

    @objc dynamic var rpeTSS: Double{
        return (100/49)*rpe*rpe*Double(seconds)/3600
    }

    override public class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String>{
        let keyPaths = super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
        switch key {
        case "rpeTSS":
            return keyPaths.union(Set(["seconds","rpe"]))
        default:
            return keyPaths
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to have stored variables in an extension no?

Comment: you're not. This solution doesn't have any stored variables. It's an old post of mine. Know a lot more now and pretty certain this is the right way to do what I was trying to do

Comment: Thanks Steven Lord for the interesting solution. I'm facing a similar need to compute a property based on 2 CoreData properties, which I then use in a SortDescriptor. I've not managed to make it work so far: I've got the error "keypath status not found in entity". I provide the key path `\MyEntity.computedProperty` in the sort descriptor, which is recognised by the autocompletion, but the error is still raised. I would be curious about how you use your property, and if you knew why it failed in my case.

Comment: I've not seen this error before. I use this feature mainly so that the GUI changes as a user edits the underlying values. The properties are used in a table which sorts via the array controllers sortDescriptors

Comment: @StevenLord Do you have to save the context before the updates are reflected in your GUI? Or, for example, is simply setting one of the underlying attributes (`rpe = 3`) enough to trigger the updated GUI?

Comment: simply setting one of the underlying attributes triggers the update in the GUI. I'm pretty certain this is the correct way to do this - I've used it extensively since posting this answer

Comment: @BenoîtL. I have the same problem(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730049/coredata-nssortdescriptor-by-computed-value-with-2-keypaths) with u. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure this is the right way to do it but it does solve the question as asked. However I would be interested if there is a 'right' way to do what I'm trying.

I managed to get it all to update by overriding the setValue(: forKey) method in my extension:

```
extension Workout{

    public override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        if key == "rpeTSS"{
            if rpeTSS == 0{
                self.rpeTSS = (100/49)*rpe*rpe*Double(seconds)/3600
            }
        return rpeTSS
        }
        return super.value(forKey: key)
    }

    public override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        if (key == "rpe") || (key == "seconds") {
            self.rpeTSS = calculateRPETSS()
        }
    }

    func calculateRPETSS() -> Double{
        return (100/49)*rpe*rpe*Double(seconds)/3600
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but...

I have an Entity class called `Person`. Here are my two classes:

Person+CoreDataProperties.swift:

```
extension Person {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Total> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var age: Int

}
```

Person+CoreDataClass.swift:

```
@objc(Person)
public class Total: NSManagedObject {

}
```

These were generated by Xcode. And then in my `ViewController` when I want to use this class I use:

```
var curPerson: Person?
let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: Singleton.s.context)!

Singleton.s.people = try Singleton.s.context.fetch(Person.fetchRequest())

// find the current person
for p in Singleton.s.people {
    if p.name == curName { // got it
        curPerson = p
        break
    }
}
```

Now I have a `Person` object to manipulate. To make a new object I use:

`let newPerson = Person(entity: personEntity, insertInto: Singleton.s.context)`

And to make sure my changes are saved I use:

`(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()`

Comment: Thanks. Thats give me something to think about. In my case I'm using bindings in the GUI and array controllers to create my objects. So currently I'm not instantiating instances of my entities. I was trying to keep it this way